# Python Ascendance and descendance

Tags: python

I apologize in advance for the basic level of my question. I would like to the print the:

- total number and identity of nodes that have 0 child, 1 child, 2 children, 3 children.
- total number of node that have 0 parent, 1 parent, 2 parents, 3 parents.

here is my simple script.
thanks.
Vicinci

```
search = []
search += search_nodes()
node_father = []
node_child = []
for i in search:
    node_father += i.get_parents()
    node_child += i.get_children()
print "Total of nodes", len(search)
print "Total of parents", len(node_father)
print "Total of children", len(node_child)
```

Comment: is that homework? If yes, it should have the "homework" tag.

Comment: Agreed. You haven't given us enough information to solve your homework problem, even if we were so inclined. Show us what you've tried so far, and how it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a map and do it yourself or use itertools.groupBy

1) Do-it-yourself way:

```
nodes_by_num_children={}
for node in search:
  children=len(node.get_children())
  if children not in nodes_by_num_children:
    nodes_by_num_children[children]=[]
  nodes_by_num_children[children].append(node)

for num, nodes in nodes_by_num_children.iteritems():
    print num
    for node in nodes:
        print node
```

2) Itertools way:

import itertools

```
search.sort(key=lambda x: len(x.get_children()))
for num_children,nodes in itertools.groupBy(search,lambda x: len(x.get_children())):
   print num_children 
   for node in nodes:
      print node
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

by_parents = defaultdict(list)
by_children = defaultdict(list)
for node in search_nodes():
    parents = node.get_parents()
    by_parents[len(parents)].append(node)
    children = node.get_children()
    by_children[len(children)].append(node)
```